# Best place for 3rd party libraries

Tags: magento2, 3rd-party-library

I'm developing very small modules and would like to put all javascript 3rd party libraries in one place to better maintain/update them and to avoid duplicating across modules.
According to the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html),"Do not put custom JS files in the lib/web directory".
So the best place is to place them in **_core**/view/frontend/web/js module ? Make module dependency to it and map js libraries in each others with requirejs-config.js ?
Or am I misunderstanding the magento doc ?

I don't think it is a good idea to place them in my theme as it is not theme related.

Comment: typo I mean **myvendor_core**/view/frontend/web/js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual solution I saw is to create "base" module and put such elements there. So if you create Vendor_Base and dependency in `etc/modules.xml` and `etc/composer.json` in child modules. If you want to deliver modules each one need to be bundled with this Vendor_Base. Custom js put in `Vendor/Base/view/frontened/web/js` and create `Vendor/Base/view/frontend/require.js` file to give them better name to use in child modules js files.